# Python: highlight word or phrase in long string

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, replace

I have a long list of sentences and I'm trying to use ANSI color codes to highlight matching strings. The input is case-insensitive but I'd like the output (i.e., positive matches) to remain case-sensitive.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from re import sub, IGNORECASE

red = '\033[31m'
nul = '\033[0m'

sentences = ["foo foo findme 123 bar bar",
             "foo findme foo bar 123 bar",
             "foo foo FindME 123 bar bar"]

for sentence in sentences:
    search_term = "findme 123"
    sentence = sub(search_term.replace(' ', '.*'), f'{red}{search_term}{nul}', sentence, flags=IGNORECASE)
    print(sentence)
```

Current output:

```
foo foo findme 123 bar bar # this is good
foo findme 123 bar         # this is bad
foo foo findme 123 bar bar # this is bad
```

Desired output:

```
foo foo findme 123 bar bar
foo foo FindME 123 bar bar
```

How do I correctly match case-sensitive strings and prevent false-positives from clobbering parts of the sentence?

I'm very open to using a library other than `re` to solve this but would generally prefer a pure-python3 method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import re

red = "\033[31m"
nul = "\033[0m"

sentences = [
    "foo foo findme 123 bar bar",
    "foo findme foo bar 123 bar",
    "foo foo FindME 123 bar bar",
]

s = "findme 123"

for sentence in sentences:
    sentence = re.sub(
        r"\b({})\b".format(re.escape(s)),
        r"{}\1{}".format(red, nul),
        sentence,
        flags=re.I,
    )
    print(sentence)
```

Prints (screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Andrej. This works with the above sample script but not with my actual script for some reason. Can you explain what ` r"\b({})\b"` does? I found that ` r"({})"` works in my actual script with searches that don't contain a space (.e.g., "findme" works, "findme 1" doesn't).

Comment: @zihobu `\b` is "word boundary". You can see the [regex here](https://regex101.com/r/XuGMq5/1)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is somewhat unrelated, but why did you prefer `import re` over `from re import ..., ..., ...`? Isn't it usually better to import only what we need?

Comment: @zihobu Me personally I'd do `import re`. For me it's easier to read.